# Why are vertebrae, specifically, so important in classification?

Tags: anatomy, phylogenetics, vertebrates

A fundamental level of animal classification is the distinction between vertebrates and invertebrates.  The vertebrata are, arguably, often classified as higher life forms than the invertebrata.  But why is the presence of the spine so important?  Why not use the simpler concept of internal bones as a classifier?

I might be missing something, but I can't think of any creature that has an endoskeleton but no spine.  Do any such creatures exist?  If not, why does classification focus on the spine and not the endoskeleton?

Comment: "If you have a spine, you're a higher form of life than things that don't." This is not true. Terms like "higher form of life" are meaningless

Comment: @CactusWoman You could say [these stratospheric bacteria](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2009/03/090318094642.htm) are literally higher forms of life!

Comment: @CactusWoman - I edited the question to make it less emphasizing on the higher/lower aspect

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**
The term *vertebrata* stems from grouping animals according to obvious gross anatomical distinguishing features as typically used in the early days of taxonomy. However, from a phylogenetic point of view, the presence of the neural crest during embryonic development, which is *unique to this subset of animals in the phylum chordata*, is a much more important distinguishing feature than the presence of *vertebrae*.

**Background**
Vertebrates belong to the **[phylum](http://www.fcps.edu/islandcreekes/ecology/classification_group_expla.htm)** *[chordata](http://eol.org/pages/694/details)*, but share some characters that make them unique. [Chordates](http://eol.org/pages/694/details), with a few exceptions, are active animals with bilaterally symmetric bodies that are longitudinally differentiated into head, trunk and tail. The most distinctive morphological features of chordates are the **notochord**, **nerve cord**, and visceral clefts and arches.

Vertebrates feature [neural crest cells](http://www.ucmp.berkeley.edu/vertebrates/vertintro.html), which sets them apart from any other group. These cells appear early in development, and only vertebrates have them. Neural crest cells form the skull and jaw bones.

The neural crest has sometimes been called the fourth germ layer because of its importance (Fig. 1). The neural crest cells produce a variety of  cell types, including (1) the neurons and glial cells of the sensory, sympathetic, and parasympathetic nervous systems, (2) the epinephrine-producing (medulla) cells of the adrenal gland, (3) the pigment-containing cells of the epidermis, and (4) many of the skeletal and connective tissue components of the head [(Gilbert, 2000](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK10065/)).

[image: Neural crest]
<sup>Fig. 1. Regions of the neural crest. The cranial neural formt the bones and cartilage of the face and neck. It also produces pigment and cranial nerves. The vagal neural crest (near somites 1–7) and the sacral neural crest (posterior to somite 28) form the parasympathetic nerves of the gut. The cardiac neural crest cells arise from the neural crest by somites 1–3. Neural crest cells of the trunk (about somite 6 through the tail) make the sympathetic neurons, and a subset of these (at the level of somites 18–24) form the medulla portion of the adrenal gland. Source: [Gilbert (2000)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK10065/)</sup>

In all, the term vertebrates is just a reflection of an apparent and obvious marker of this group of animals, namely the presence of *vertebrae*, but their distinguishing most important feature is the presence of the neural crest during development.

<sub>**Reference**

**-** [Gilbert. *Developmental Biology*, 6<sup>th</sup> ed. Sunderland (MA): Sinauer Associates (2000)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK10065/)</sub>